# Автоматический перенос фигурной скобки в VS на новую строку

Tags: visual-studio, c++, visual-studio-2012

В Visual Studio принят такой стиль кода:

```
class MyClass
{
//pass
};
```

Как его поменять на:

```
class MyClass {
//pass
};
```

Answer (score 6):

для C# это делается так: Сервис -> Параметры -> Текстовый редактор -> C# -> Форматирование -> Новые строки. И далее выбираете те или иные флаги, интересующие вас. Как это сделать для С++ я, к сожалению, не нашел. Возможно, есть возможность настройки и для плюсов. 
У меня это работало в VS 2012 Ultimate. В других версиях, вероятно, будет то же самое

Comment: да, c C# у них все хорошо((

Comment: @derketzer в 2012 update 4 настройка для C++ есть

Answer (score 1):

На C++ VS2019:

**Tools > Options... > C/C++ > Code Style > Formatting > New Lines**

"*Position of Open Braces*" поменять на "*Keep on the same line, butt add a space before*" для всех случаев, которые вам нужны.

Answer (score 0):

сервис-параметры-текстовый редактор-табуляция::отступы

Comment: не дало никакого эффекта (VS 2012)

Answer (score 0):

может кому то и понадобится сейчас.
средства > параметры > текстовый редактор > C/C++> стиль кода > форматирование > новые строки
и тут уже подбирайте настройки под себя) отметьтесь если вам помогло, if (не сложно);