# Фигурные скобки

Tags: unity3d, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, настройки

Я недавно программировал unity код в visual studio code, но сейчас я решил перейти на visual studio и заметил разницу при переносе фигурных скобок:

**Visual Studio Code**:

```
private void Update() {

}
```

**Visual Studio**:

```
private void Update() 
{

}
```

Хотелось бы, что бы открывающая фигурная скобка оставалась на строке с "Update()". Можно ли где-то в настойках это изменить?

PS: Пользуюсь Visual Studio 2019, установил "Разработку игр с помощью Unity"

Comment: Посмотрите ответы здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/180686/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81-%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-vs-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83 если что-то подойдёт, помечу ваш вопрос как дубликат

Comment: @CrazyElf, скорее всего дубликат будет, в VS 2019 настройки там же, от себя проверил: `Tools -> Options ->Text Editor -> C# -> Code Style -> Formatting ->  New Lines` (Сервис -> Параметры -> Текстовый редактор -> C# -> Форматирование -> Новые строки) и настраиваем как удобно, в окне свойств есть пример как будет изменен формат.

Comment: Сорри, я просто нашел другое решение и оно мне не помогло, спасибо тебе огромное